# How can I add a fragment to the top of a vertical linear layout on Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, android-linearlayout

Currently, I'm adding a new fragment (Post) to a vertical linear layout (that is inside a scroll view) like this:

```
val post1 = Post()
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(vb.svLayout.id, post1).commit()
```

This code appends the fragment at the bottom of the linear layout, but now I want to add a post at the top of the linear layout. How can I accomplish that?

My XML code:

```xml
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/sv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/svLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Background:

I display a list of posts in a scroll view. But now I want to append new posts above the other ones. I download the new ones from the back-end via an HTTP request.

In the end, I want to make an infinite scroll view that loads new posts dynamically. So when I scroll to the top I request new posts from the API and want to add them to the top of the scroll view, and the same thing for the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

What I can assume from your question is that you have some views and a fragment view which is present at the bottom of the LinearLayout and when navigating to a certain fragment you want that to appear at the top of the LinearLayout.

There isn't any method to reorder the layouts. One thing you can do is remove all your views existing in the vertical LinearLayout and add the view you want at the top and again add all of the other views.

```
ViewGroup parent = findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout);
View fragment = findViewById(R.id.frag);
View view = findViewById(R.id.view);
parent.removeView(view);
parent.addView(view); // Replacing the view from top to bottom
```

Comment: I display a list of posts in a scroll view. But now I want to append new posts to the top of the other ones. I download the new ones from the back-end via http request.
In the end I want to make an infinite scroll view that loads new posts dynamically. So when I scroll to the top I request new posts from the api and want to add them to the top of the scroll view, and the same thing for the bottom.

Comment: This can be done easily using recycler view , creating a list of posts and inserting the new posts at the start of the list